# ¿Cómo puedo realizar una consulta multitabla con condiciones en Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

estoy intentando realizar un buscador en Laravel y me he quedado trancado.

El objetivo del formulario es encontrar **Aeronaves** dentro del sistema, el detalle es que dichas aeronaves están relacionadas a unos Usuarios mediante la ID de los mismos (id_users).

Entonces, quiero que el buscador pueda encontrar las aeronaves por todas sus caracteristicas, es decir: Siglas, Seriales, Estado, Etc... Pero tambien que pueda ser encontrada por el NOMBRE DEL USUARIO, es ahí donde me quedé.

¿Como puedo hacer una consulta donde revise si el texto del formulario ($query) es igual a: Las siglas de las aeronaves, o seriales, o estado, o la ID del usuario vinculado a la aeronave (Sabiéndose que los usuarios no buscaran por ID sino por nombre)

```php
$query = 'Texto Introducido por el formulario'

$aeronaves = Aeronave::where('siglas', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                       ->orwhere('seriales', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                       ->orwhere('estado', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                       ->orwhere('id_users', 'like', AQUI NO SE QUE PONER)
```

En fin, los usuarios deben colocar el NOMBRE del dueño de la Aeronave, y de ese nombre yo necesito conseguir las ID que pueden estar vinculadas a la aeronave.

Pero si tengo mas de 2 usuarios con el mismo nombre quiero que se muestren las aeronaves de ambos!

Estoy trancado en esto, seria util una orientación.

///////////////////////////////**AÑADO LO QUE QUE REALIZADO**///////////

```
$aeronaves = Aeronave::select(['aeronaves.*', 'users.nombre as u_nombre', 'users.apellido as u_apellido', 'modelos.modelo as m_modelo', 'modelos.marca as m_marca'])
                                    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'aeronaves.id_users')
                                    ->join('modelos', 'modelos.id', '=', 'aeronaves.id_modelos')
                                    ->where('siglas', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                                    ->orwhere('seriales', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                                    ->orwhere('estado', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                                    ->orwhere('u_nombre', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                                    ->orwhere('u_apellido', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                                    ->orwhere('m_marca', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                                    ->orwhere('m_modelo', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(9);
```

Me devuelve este error en el AJAX

```
message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'u_nombre' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `aeronaves` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `aeronaves`.`id_users` inner join `modelos` on `modelos`.`id` = `aeronaves`.`id_modelos` where `siglas` like %yv% or `seriales` like %yv% or `estado` like %yv% or `u_nombre` like %yv% or `u_apellido` like %yv% or `m_marca` like %yv% or `m_modelo` like %yv%)"
```

Comment: Que tipo de dato es el de la columna `id_users`? Tienes definida la relación entre Aeronave y User?

Comment: id_users es un entero (FK de la tabla Users) y si está definida la relación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes utilizar join, te explico un ejemplo breve

```
//Coloca con asterisco todos los elementos de la tabla aeronaves y cada uno de los elementos de usuarios, te recomiendo cambies su nombre con as
//Todos los elementos deben estar en un array
//Si no necesitas el resto de los elementos de las tablas secundarias, debes tener cuidado con los id de todas las tablas, pero si es posible seleccionarlas de esta forma, de hecho no necesitarias el select
Aeronave::join('usuarios', 'usuarios.id', '=', 'aeronaves.id_users')
->where('usuarios.nombre', 'like', "%{$query}%")
->orWhere('usuarios.apellido', 'like', "%{$query}%")
->orWhere(
//Condicionales originales
)->get();
```

De esta forma haces un join a la tabla usuarios y los "concatenas" con los registros de las aeronaves

Comment: Y si además de los usuarios tengo una tabla con los modelos de aeronaves para sacar el nombre de los modelos y la marca, hago otro JOIN? o la funcion debe ser diferente?

Comment: Puedes hacer otro join con la misma sintaxis, pero asegurate de que en la función select() coloques correctamente los nombres de los campos que necesites para que no se repitan con los anteriores.

Comment: Intenté como me dices, pero me devuelve un error cuando entra en esa parte del codigo, te dejé la funcion como la puse en la pregunta

Comment: Cambia los nombres de los campos del query de esa tabla como en mi respuesta editada `->where('usuarios.nombre', 'like', "%{$query}%")`

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, creo que debrías seguir la sugerencia en la documentación de [Agrupar las llamadas `orWhere`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#parameter-grouping):

> Siempre debe agrupar las llamadas `orWhere` para evitar un comportamiento inesperado cuando se aplican ámbitos globales.

Luego puedes [Consultar existencia de relación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) combinándola con `orWhere`: `orWhereHas`. Limitando los resultados en función de la existencia de esa relación y poniendo las condiciones "where" en la consulta, lo que te permite agregar restricciones personalizadas a la restricción de relación.

```php
// el primer where() es para agrupar las llamadas orWhere
$aeronaves = Aeronave::where(function ($aeronaves) use ($query) {
    $aeronaves->where('siglas', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
        ->orWhere('seriales', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
        ->orWhere('estado', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
        // aquí consultas la existencia de la relación, 
        // con la condición de que el atributo 'name' sea 'like' (como) el dato que le pasas en la variable $query
        // cambia 'name' por el atributo del model User que quieras comparar
        ->orWhereHas('user', function ($users) use ($query) {
            $users->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
        });
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Excelente, probaré asi... pero si quiero hacerlo con paginación? no dara error el paginate() en lugar del get()??

Comment: No debería darte error con paginate